# Recursion of a Map producing another Map with some conversions

Tags: java, recursion

I have a Map, the Object in this case may be one of, Number, String, List, Array or Date.
I need to make a copy of this Map but in the result I need to do some conversion if the object is of type Date (the conversion details are not important).

I guess I need recursion ti read through the Map & sub maps, but cant for the life of me figure out how to do this. Can anyone help?

I can figure out how to read through the complete map, but can';t figure out how to out put it.

Here's a sort of outline (non-working) of what I want to do - it doesn't create the output map.

```
private void convertResult(Object o) {
     Map<String, Object> returnMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    if (o instanceof Map) {
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry: ((Map<Object, Object>)o).entrySet()) {
            convertResult(entry.getValue());    
        }
        return;
    }  else if (o instanceof List) {
        for (Object li: (List) o) {
            convertResult(li);  
        }
        return;     
    } else if (o instanceof Number) {
        return;
    } else if (o instanceof Boolean) {
        return;
    } else if (o instanceof String) {
        return;
    } else if (o instanceof Date) {
        // convert the date here
        return;
    } else if (o.getClass().isArray()) {
        JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
        for (Object li: (Object[])o) {
            convertResult(li);  
        }
        return;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported object " + o.getClass());
    }

}
```

Comment: So, you have a Map full of Integers, Strings, Dates, Lists, Arrays, and more Maps? Who's been drunk programming?

Comment: a) returnMap is never used. new JsonArray the same b) You claim `Object in this case may be one of, Number, String, List, Array or Date` but you check for Map too. c) if (o instanceof Number) and so on can be grouped by `if (o instanceof x) || (o instanceof ...` d) Since you don't return anything, you have to modify the data in place. Since the only data, in the end, which is modified, is of type `date`, you're maybe returning a new date, which is ignored? e) Do you want to output the map, or return it - return a modified map, containing the same Lists and Arrays or copies of them? Unclear!

Comment: Very funny. The Map is defined as `Map<String,Object>` and the Object in this case may be one of the types I mentioned. Not drunk - there is a perfectly good reason for this.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the Map may it self contain a Map. Hence the recursion. I know that there are some unused fields in the code - i did mention it was non-working code. I included it here to give some idea of what I was thinking. I want to return the Map, or return a modified Map containing all the same data apart from a converted date.

Comment: If you convert the map in place, which is possible, if all Dates can be modified in place, you don't need to return a Map. You can generate a copy before, if you need to keep the original as well. But we still don't know where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of list and map you should take the result given and add it as an entry to the map.

```
Object result = convertResult(entry.getValue());
returnMap.put(entry.getKey(),result);
```

Not sure if the name of the function for getting the key is entry.getKey(), but I think you get my point. convertResult() is returning the conversion of the entry.getValue(), so you should add it to the map. The recurssion is finishing when it finds a Integer, Date or whatever. In this cases you should return the converted value (even if you don't touch it) as it is the value you will put in the map.